# React Scroll to bottom of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am apending text to a textarea then attempting to scroll to the bottom to keep the latest within view. However, in doing this I appear to be crashing the browser / running out of memory. Can anyone help optimise this code?

```
//Appending text and calling scroll function
this.setState({ transcriptText: this.state.transcriptText + resp.log })
this.scrollToBottom();

//Textarea
<TextArea
  ref={textLog => this.textLog = textLog}
  autosize={{ minRows: 10, maxRows: 15 }}
  value={this.state.transcriptText}
>
</TextArea>

//Scrolling
scrollToBottom = () => {
    const textLogContainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.textLog);
    if(textLogContainer){
        textLogContainer.scrollTop = textLogContainer.scrollHeight;
    }
};
```

Full

```
componentDidMount() {
    const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, { transports: ['websocket'] });
    socket.emit('onboarding', { id: uploadId });
    socket.on('transcript_log', function (resp) {
        this.setState({ transcriptText: this.state.transcriptText + resp.log })
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It's easier to use the newer `React.createRef()` and use `componentDidUpdate()` as a trigger:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.textLog = React.createRef();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.textLog.current.scrollTop = this.textLog.current.scrollHeight;
}

render() {
    return(
        <textarea ref={this.textLog} value={this.state.transcriptText} />
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the `.current` property? It turns out that adding that is essential to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` when you have a ref, change it to just check if the ref is null and then change `scrollTop`.

Like this

```
scrollToBottom = () => {
    if(this.textLog){
        this.textLog.scrollTop = this.textLog.scrollHeight;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with checking if `this.textLog` exists, but seems unnecessary since it is always set on component mount.

Comment: Should this be this.textLog.scrollTop = this.textLog.scrollHeight? As textLogContainer does not exist if I remove the DOM line?

Comment: Yea you are probably right. I use flow in a lot of my apps and you have to do this before you use a ref but without it you probably don't get a warning.

Comment: Yea sorry I fixed it.

Comment: I changed it in my code, it isn't scrolling to the bottom anymore?

Comment: Can you post the entire component I don't see how what we changed would stop it from working.

Comment: Added in the full componentdidmount() Thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160291/discussion-between-elliot-reeve-and-dakota).

Answer (score 2):

I struggled long and hard to figure this out.  I've got a ReactJS app that reads logfiles from services running on a machine, and I wanted the most recent log message to scroll into view.  Here is a somewhat complete example of my LogFileTextBox control using React Hooks:

```
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const LogFileTextBox = (props) => {
  const logText = props.logText;
  const logFileName = props.logFileName;
  const textArea = useRef();
  
  // After render, this scrolls the textArea to the bottom.
  useEffect(() => {
    const area = textArea.current;
    area.scrollTop = area.scrollHeight;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>&nbsp;</Row>
        <Row>&nbsp;</Row>
        <Row>
          <Col></Col>
          <Col>
            <h6>Current Log: {logFileName}</h6>
          </Col>
          <Col></Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <textarea                 
              value={logText}
              readOnly={true}
              ref={textArea}    // This links the useRef() hook to this object in the dom
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LogFileTextBox;
```